# Using of a system call in c

Tags: c, architecture

I would like to create a program name patch witch recives a FILENAME and a string.In the file there is the string 'allis'.I need to replace each time the string 'allis' appears in the text with the string I recieved as an input.
I need to use only system call and not the standat libary.

This is an example code on how the code should look like(this just example of the structure it is not the mission, the code writes "allis" word instead of "hello world"):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc , char* argv[], char* envp[]) 
{   

   char buf[6];
   int fd = open(argv[1],O_WRONLY,0777);
   if (fd == -1)
      exit(1);
   write(fd,"hello world!\n",13);
   close(fd);


   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
   if (fd == -1)
      exit(1);

   read(fd,buf,5);
   buf[5]='\0';
   close(fd);

   fd = open(argv[1],O_WRONLY,0777);
   if (fd == -1)
      exit(1);
   write(fd,"allis",5);
   close(fd);



   return 0;


}
```

I need to use the system call lseek but I dont know how I should use it because I dont know where in the text 'allis' is located and what happens if the string i get as an input is bigger than 'allis' I need to move all the text to the right or something because I will override other text.

EDIT:
I wrote a code which check char by char (instead of allis its shira and it replace it with sergay)It actually worked. and than I tried to change the code to work with argv[1] and argv[2] as needed and it didnt work I revert back to the code that originally worked for me and its just doesnt work now!! The problem is that the buf doesnt take 5 character (only 1)
and believe me or not it worked before.

The code :

```
         #include <sys/types.h>
         #include <sys/stat.h>
         #include <fcntl.h>
          #include <unistd.h>
         #include <stdio.h>
          #define SYS_WRITE 1
         #define STDOUT 1
          extern int system_call();
    int main(int argc , char* argv[], char* envp[]) 
   {    

char buf[5];

int index1=0,index2=0;//the index of the file
int fd1;
int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1) 
         return 1;
fd1 = open("copytext.txt",O_WRONLY,0777);
     if (fd1 == -1) 
         return 1;

 int i =0; 
while (fd!=-1){//while there is still info to read
    printf("enter the %d loop\n",i);
    i++;
    if(read(fd,buf,5) == 0 ) break;//read 5 chars from the file //buf[5]='\0';//!! not sure about this
    printf("the buffer is: %s\n",buf);         
        if ((buf[0]=='s') && (buf[1]=='h') && (buf[2]=='i') && (buf[3]=='r') && (buf[4]=='a'))// if (strcmp(buf,"shira")==0)//if we found shira
        {
            write(fd1,"sergay",6);//replace shira
            index2 = index2 + 6;
            if(lseek(fd1,index2,SEEK_SET) < 0) break;
           index1 = index1 + 5;//size of shira
            if(lseek(fd,index1,SEEK_SET) < 0) break;
        }
     else {//we did not find shira;

         write(fd1,buf,1);//write only one
         index2++;
         if(lseek(fd1,index2,SEEK_SET) < 0) break;
         index1++;
        if(lseek(fd,index1,SEEK_SET) < 0) break;
     }

}       


 printf("get out of the loop\n");
char buffer[index2];
fd1 = open("copytext.txt", O_RDONLY);
if (fd1 == -1) 
         return 1;
if(lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_SET) < 0)  return 1;
if(read(fd1,buffer,index2) == 0 ) return 1;


   fd = open("file.txt",O_WRONLY,0777);

     if (fd == -1) 
         return 1;
     if(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET) < 0) return 1;
     write(fd,buffer,index2);

close(fd);
close(fd1);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Usually, in situation like this, you open the source file in reading, and you open in the same place a new file in writing. (Note the same place, it's important). You can add ".tmp" or ".whatever" in order to have a uniq name. Then, you read a line from source file, you "replace" each pattern, and then you write the result in the new file. At the end, you close the 2 file, and move the new file at the place of the old. You rename it with overwriting the destination. This way, either you have the old file untouched in case of an error, or the correct new.

Comment: Read the file and write the output while replacing the string in a temporary file as @Tom's says. However, you don't need to do it line by line -- you only need to keep a buffer as long as the string to be replaced.

Comment: @Acorn Well, it's more subtle than that. Let's say that what he want to replace is "hello" and we read 5 char by 5 char as you suggest. If my file is "hello world", then OK. But if it's "Hey, hello world", it will fail. The "line by line" is a quick and reliable if you pattern doesn't contain "\n". If you want to truly replace any pattern, then a good algo is to write only what we are sure that not contain the pattern. That imply having a bigger buffer, and shifting the end of the buffer at the beginning each time.

Comment: @Tom's  can you please provide a code that show the use of the system calls?

Comment: @ShmuelNiraev hardly, it's not the purpose of SO to provide code. It's up to you to code something and ask us a question when you have something that you can't resolve. Moreover, it seem that it's school work related. If the algorithm that both of us have proposed is good for you, try to implement one.

Comment: @Tom's I did not suggest reading "5 chars by 5 chars"; what I said is that you need to keep looking ahead up to the length of the string to be matched. In other words, you have a FSM which copies characters except when matching (partially or fully). This approach uses a fixed amount of memory. However, "reading line by line" requires allocating memory and does not work if the pattern contains the line break.

Comment: @Acorn pattern to replace = "aaabbaa", file = "aaaabbaa". How do you implemente this state machine ? Because the good 'a' is the second, and the first 'a' will trigger the "do not copy" part. However, I agree with you : reading line by line indeed require memory, and will, as I stated before, only work if you don't have "\n" in your pattern.

Comment: @Tom's No, the first `a` just goes to another state, as the second and third. Then, if you receive a fourth `a`, you loop. If you get `b`, you go to a fifth state. If you get anything else, you go back to the start; etc. The entire NFA/DFA should take you 7 states. (...)

Comment: @Tom's (...) If you want to convince yourself that you can do it with a DFA, think that this is the same as a search with a regexp pattern of `aaabbaa`. Yet another way to do it in fixed memory is a sliding buffer of 7 chars where you test every time whether the string matches. It is a little nice [automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) problem to write it in several ways :-)

Comment: @Tom's In case it helps, I drew a quick DFA using a regexp-to-DFA nice tool & minimizer I just found online: https://i.imgur.com/ANie4Sy.png (don't mind the last state; and `c` means anything else). Cheers!

Comment: @Acorn I agree that you can, but it's only when you know what pattern you will search. If you doesn't know how the pattern will look like, can you still make a reliable fsm ? I will look at your link and try to think on this.

Comment: @Another solution that I see is using a buffer to the exacte length of the pattern. then you read the file char by char : if letter is not the first in the pattern, then write on output file, else, stock it in the buffer. if all the following letter are the pattern, then write replacement string in ouput file and re-do the read. If one letter in the buffer "broke" the pattern, then try to find a new beginning of the pattern in the buffer. If there is not, simply write the buffer in ouput file, if there is, shift the buffer and go on. Sound simple, no memory consuption. A little naive maybe.

Comment: @Tom's You can always construct a FSM for this (of course, you won't know the number of states needed until they tell you the pattern, but that is fine -- 1 allocation). About your second comment: indeed, you got it -- that is the approach I hinted you at when I said "sliding buffer of 7 chars where you test every time whether the string matches" (it is an easy way to convince yourself that it can be be done with finite memory, even if it does more comparisons than necessary)! If you like this kind of stuff, be sure to pick up a good book about AT, it is very worth it :-)

Comment: @Tom's I added the code in the edit above

Comment: @Acorn  I added the code in the edit above

Comment: @ShmuelNiraev Oh god ... Look like appart from guiding you from the start to the end, there will be 1000 comment. Your code is too .... messy. Why do you use lseek ? what's index and index2 ? Okay, you have serious flaw on how you can use "file" (read/write) in C language. First, it seem that is an assignement (schoolwork). Is it the case ? Are you allowed to use dynamic allocation ?

Comment: @Tom's I have to use lseek it’s part of the assignment anI think I can use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @ShmuelNiraev The only way lseek is a mandatory use is if you try to do the change in the file itself ... But boy, it will be one hell of road if that's the case. If you are allowed to open a temporary file like we have suggested you, then lseek is useless. Can you clarify this point with your teacher ? Also, a good starting point for you, given the previous code, is to realise a copy of the file with either a buffer, or char by char.

Comment: @Tom's I have found the problem it was a bug in file.txt after removing the file the code works

Comment: @ShmuelNiraev ??? if something in the file provok a bug in the code, then the code is at fault, not the file >< . Well, if you have solved your problem, good to you.